# Unable to access “WINDOWS”

Tags: ntfs

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/dany/Data: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/dany/Data"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: Hello @user184395. Well, the error explains something but it will be useful if you provide enough details on what is your problem and/or which behavior you expect in certain case. As I can see, you have dual boot or you are in a Live Session and you try to access to a "slept" (suspended) Windows OS (May be Win8?). If you have send Windows to Sleep instead of Shutting down, you may receive this kind of errors when trying to mount the partition. Please edit your question's title and contents in order to include sufficient details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will cause if you have hibernated windows or shutdown windows 8(without restarting). Here you will get a solution.

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8, you will need to disable "Fast startup".

Here is the link for it-

[Disable Fast Startup](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/what-is-fast-startup-windows-8-disable-it/)

Now you would be able to mount your ntfs partition.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that you made boot able device using ubuntu and windows(8/8.1).
This happens because your windows has setup as fast startup by default..
This fast startup might hibernate your disk sometimes.
Hibernated disk can't be accessed in ubuntu as this may cause the loss of data.
Just make the fast startup disable in windows from power options..
Shut down windows properly and turn on again.
I am having windows 8.1 pro but I am facing a problem that windows don't allow me to change fast startup to toggle to enable/disable as it is enabled by default, as an administrator also..
If you facing same than I started doing restart in windows rather than shutdown..
Start up feature of windows is not affected in restarting option so just select restart option and after your device gets restarted, select ubuntu..
Your all disk will run properly..
This will work for sure...